# How to pre-load pre-defined arrays in iOS development using Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, swift2, preload

I am currently working on a neural network implementation on an iPhone iOS App. I have obtained the weights, which are pre-defined arrays read from a text file. Let me provide a little background on that:

There are eight variables and dimensions are as follows:

```
W1 : 5x5x1x32  [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 32x1x5x5]
W2 : 5x5x32x64 [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 64x32x5x5]
W3 : 3136x1024 [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 3136x1024]
W4 : 1024x14   [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 1024x14]

B1 : 1x32      [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 32]
B2 : 1x64      [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 64]
Bf1: 1x1024    [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 1024]
Bf2: 1x14      [In Swift or Obj-C convention: 14]
```

The variables are saved in a .txt file as a one dimensional flat array and then reshaped into the Swift Multidimensional-Array. However, none of these array values will need to be changed or overwritten.

Just reading the variables takes almost 6 seconds, whereas I believe we can pre-load the variables beforehand in the app. I guess can be made possible through CoreData! Can someone suggest an effective solution to this such that I can load the variables as an array as above?

Comment: Confused.  If you already have code that turns the data into a swift array, then use the same side to print the array in swift format, cut/paste into a data.swift file and use it as a datasource for your project.

Comment: I did not get you. Do you mean copy pasting the entire array of such a bigger size and then use them? I want to pre-load them so that while running on the app, they don't take memory or slower down the performance as a result.

Comment: While you could include those constants in code, loading them seems clean. If it takes 6 seconds to load, optimize that. As you can easily load 50 MB/s+, you just might have a performance bug. Storing them in binary format should speed up things as well.

Comment: I am actually saving them in txt file which takes around 1.7 seconds; but reshaping them to multidimensional array, which is necessary for the code takes more 4 seconds. Is there a way to optimize it?